# Adding/removing classes to/from element scrolls page to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have to following code:

```
const burger = $("#burger-menu");
const main = $("#main");
const menu = $("#menu");

function showSideMenu() {
  $("#menu").removeClass("hidden");
  $("#main").addClass("blurry");
  $("#main").addClass("fixed");
  burger[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].classList.add("burger-top-animate");
  burger[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].classList.add("burger-bottom-animate");
}

function hideSideMenu(event) {
  $("#menu").addClass("hidden");
  $("#main").removeClass("blurry");
  $("#main").removeClass("fixed");
  burger[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].classList.remove("burger-top-animate");
  burger[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].classList.remove(
    "burger-bottom-animate"
  );
}

burger.click((event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (menu.hasClass("hidden")) showSideMenu();
  else hideSideMenu();
});
```

the burger click event handles a collapsing sidebar menu(hiding/showing). It behaves as expected, except it scrolls the page to the top. I can't explain to myself how that might be happening and I couldn't find the problem anywhere else.

The prevent default does not change as a thing.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is it still happening if you won't add the "fixed" class?

Comment: I just found the problem... it is the fixed class that I am adding to the element. Position fixed apparently scrolls the page to top

Comment: Glad to hear that. I've added a solution fix for you in the answers. Update if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The `position:fixed` property added to the element causes these.
Consider programeticly setting the blur back on the selected element after pressing it using `element.focus()`.

```
burger.click((event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (menu.hasClass("hidden")) {
      showSideMenu();
      event.target.focus() //--added line
  
  else hideSideMenu();
});
```

Haven't tested it myself.

Maybe wraping the focus statement in setTimeout, or menu.onfocus will be needed